# Is it possible to run two or more Azure functions simultanously?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have function app(by default it is consumption plan) which is created by visual studio and has multiple functions including timer trigger and HTTP trigger. So am having some confusion how azure function runs?

does timer trigger stop execution of other function when any other function runs?

Example: When HTTP trigger runs which takes long time to process if in between my timer trigger runs(which runs for every 5 minutes) it is stopping execution of HTTP trigger for 5 minutes.

Does any azure function runs one by one or two functions at a time?.

If I go app service plan for function app. will the same happens while execution of azure function ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, many functions can run at the same time.

Functions run independently from each other, except they consume shared resources (CPU / memory). The status of the timer triggered function should have no effect on whether HTTP function is triggered.

Comment: Mikhail is correct. I just want to add that because Functions in the same Function App share the same resources, there may be side-effects depending of on the resource consumption patterns of the Functions. If both Functions requires high CPU/memory, I would suggest splitting up the Functions into different Function Apps to avoid resource contention.